# Форматирование даты datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Есть дата '24.05.2022' нужно перевести её в формат '2022.05.24'

```
import datetime as dt
date = '24.05.2022'
print(dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%Y.%m.%d").date())
```

После выполнения кода получаю ошибку

```
ValueError: time data '24.05.2022' does not match format '%Y.%m.%d'
```

Уже не понимаю в чем может быть причина. Как это сделать более практично?

Comment: `dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%d.%m.%Y')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import datetime as dt

date = '24.05.2022'
date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, "%d.%m.%Y")

new_date = date.strftime("%Y.%m.%d")
print(new_date)
# 2022.05.24
```